# Remove Chrome autofill for HTML forms

Tags: html, google-chrome, xampp

I have created a simple form in HTML which has two fields: Username and Password, and then a Log in button. 
When I run the page in Chrome it fills the two fields with my XAMPP-phpmyadmin username and password into the fields and highlights them yellow.
How can I completely remove this so they are blank. Thanks

HTML form code:

```
<html>


    <form action= "entryformlogon.php" method = "post" autocomplete="off">
            Username: <input type="text" name="Username"><br>
            Password: <input type="password" name="Password"><br>
                      <input type="submit" value="Log in">
    </form>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

autocomplete= "off" must be added to every input element. i.e.

```
<input type="text" name="Username" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: I just tried, look at: http://jsfiddle.net/yq3t5b9p/  when run in jsfiddle the forms are blank however when run in chrome the problem is still occuring

Comment: It seems a decent workaround is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill

Answer (score 0):

> *Chrome it fills the two fields with my XAMPP-phpmyadmin username and password into the fields and highlights them yellow. How can I completely remove this so they are blank.* @Charley Baker

This readonly-fix worked for me:

**fix browser autofill in: readonly and set writeble on focus** (at mouse click and tabbing through fields)

```
 <input type="password" readonly  
     onfocus="$(this).removeAttr('readonly');"/>
```

By the way, **some more information** on Chrome and Safari auto fill behaviour:

*Sometimes even autocomplete=off would not prevent to fill in credentials* into wrong fields, but not user or nickname field. I guess, the Chrome and Safari look for a password field to insert your saved credentials. Then it **autofills *username* into the nearest textlike-input field , that appears prior the password field** in DOM (just guessing due to observation). As the browser is the last instance and you can not directly control it, but the read-only trick above fixes it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

For latest version of chrome

```
<input type="password" name="whatever" autocomplete="new-password" />
```

older version

```
<input type="password" name="whatever" autocomplete="false" />
```

or

```
<input type="password" name="whatever" autocomplete="off" />
```